# Get index from JSONArray by passing object in Android

Tags: java, android

I am having JSONArray which contains JSONObjects. Now I want to find the index by passing JSONObject.

```
JSONArray arrSongs; //Assume i have the array of JSONObjects.
JSONObject currentJsonObj; //currentJsonObj is one of the object in arrSongs.
```

Now i want to find the index of `currentJsonObj` from `arrSongs` array.

Comment: what have you tried? do you have any code to post? what does your JSON look like?...

Comment: @Onheiron: Updated my question, can you please check.

Comment: how do you identify a song? How do you tell if a Song object equals another? Also are you willing to use some libraries? Finally, can you post the JSON itself?

Comment: currentJsonObj is filled up from the arrSongs on click of  Songs ListView and moves to detail screen to show player screen. In detail screen of player, i have prev and next buttons. So if i click on prev or next i want to get the current index of the object from arrSongs by using currentJsonObj and want to move to next/prev.

Comment: so you have an activity with the list and another activity with the details? Where do you keep your jsonArray? is it in the shared preferences, is it a global variable, do you pass it as an extra to the details activity? are you willing to use some libraries? do songs have and id to identify them?

Comment: I pass the currentJsonObj as extra to the detail activity, where as the jsonArray is in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code may help you. Try this.

```
JSONArray jsonArray=Obj.getJSONArray("ArrayJsonName");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String objname= jsonObj.getString("object_name");
    ...
}
```

Comment: i want to get the index of the object from array.